# "Require valid-user" in "<Files>" section of .htaccess not password protecting directory

Tags: htaccess, apache

I am trying to lock a folder called *locked* with the encrypted user passwords stored in .htpasswd.  This does not work:

```
AuthUserFile /srv/http/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login Required"
<Files "locked" >
    Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<Files>` is designed for specifying files, not directories. E.g:

```
<Files admin.php>
    deny from all
</Files>
```

*Use one of the following:*

- `<DirectoryMatch>`
- `<Directory>`
- `<Location>`
- `<LocationMatch>`

But it should be noted that you must have mod_setenvif and mod_auth enabled, virtual host with `AllowOverride AuthConfig` and take note that `<location>` and `<LocationMatch>` only work in the virtual host configuration, i.e `/sites-enabled/example.conf`.

But there is a much easier way than any of the above...

*Simple create another .htaccess file in the directory you want to protect:*

```
 AuthName "restricted stuff"
 AuthType Basic
 AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/httpd/users
 require valid-user*
```

Comment: Both `<Directory...>` _and_ `<Location...>` wrappers are server config only. `.htaccess` in the appropriate directory is the userland equivalent of the `<Directory>` wrapper, so as you suggest, you just put it in the directory you want to protect. _Aside:_ Why is mod_setenvif_ required here? (It's enabled by default anyway.) +1